What exactly does "Auto-select" checkbox mean in the IntelliJ 2024 dialog for "New Project" > Java > Gradle > Groovy > Gradle version?
The Auto-select checkbox obviously disables my choice of versions of Gradle. But then what does IntelliJ do in selecting a version of Gradle?

Where does it find Gradle versions? Those bundled within IntelliJ – And wouldn't that be only one version? Or does it consider Gradle installations I made manually on my machine?
By what rules does IntelliJ choose a particular Gradle?

I tried clicking the question-mark icon (?) in the lower left corner. But that documentation is lacking in these details.


It mean the latest version of Gradle will be automatically selected instead of using the version that you specify:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/gradle.html

Gradle version: if the wrapper option is selected, the latest Gradle distribution will be used unless you unselect the Auto-select option and select the specific version from the drop-down list.
Alternatively, if the Local installation was selected then the version you defined locally is used.


And where does it find those multiple Gradle installations? Within IntelliJ or the ones I manually installed?

I believe the wrapper will download the latest version from https://gradle.org/releases/
